# Node for-loop callback required

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, event-loop, asynccallback

I want to change the **Tags** format which I am fetching form one of the collections. **Tags** data contains some **KC** ids in an array which I am using to get **KC** data and insert in **TagUnit** to get final response format.

```
var newTags = Tags.map(function(TagUnit) {
    for (var i = 0; i < TagUnit.kcs.length; i++) {
        KCArray = [];
        KC.findById(TagUnit.kcs[i], function(error, data) {
            KCMap = {};
            KCMap['kc_id'] = data._id;
            KCMap['kc_title'] = data.title;
            KCArray.push(KCMap);
            if (KCArray.length == TagUnit.kcs.length) {
                TagUnit.kcs = KCArray;
            }
        });
     }
     return TagUnit;
});

response.send(JSON.stringify(newTags));
```

But I am not getting desired result. Response is giving out **Tag** data in initial for instead of formatted form. I guess it is due to event looping. I will be grateful if someone can help me with this.

**Edit: ** I am using MongoDB as database and mongoose as ORM.

Comment: Have you looked into [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=de)? You are right that your problem is due to the event-loop. `newTags` is not computed completely most-likely when calling `response.send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using promises to manage your async operations which is now the standard in ES6.  You don't say what database you're using (it may already have a promise-based interface).  If it doesn't, then we manually promisify `KC.findById()`:

```
function findById(key) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        KC.findById(key, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Then, assuming you can do all these find operations in parallel, you can use `Promise.all()` to both keep track of when they are all done and to order them for you.

```
var allPromises = Tags.map(function(TagUnit) {
    var promises = TagUnit.kcs.map(function(key) {
        return findById(key).then(function(data) {
            // make resolved value be this object
            return {kc_id: data._id, kc_title: data.title};
        });
    });
    // this returns a promise that resolves with an array of the kc_id and kc_title objects
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        return {
             _id: TagUnit._id,
             kcs: results
        };
    });
});

// now see when they are all done
Promise.all(allPromises).then(function(results) {
    response.send(JSON.stringify(results));
}).catch(function(err) {
    // send error response here
});
```

Comment: I am trying to test the solution. Meanwhile just for information, my database is mongoDB and ORM is mongoose.

Comment: @Rusty - It was a little hard for me to tell what kind of final result you wanted.  This code gives you an array of arrays of objects each object contain `kc_id` and `kc_title` because that's what I thought your original code was trying to generate.

Comment: I want the **Response** to go in following format. `{ "tag_id": "nienemk29290hu38", "kcs": { "kc_id": "nmdkwmswmwjm4944", "kc_title": "ABC"}`. Your solution seems almost close to what I am getting a little hard time doing final formatting.

Comment: @Rusty - Are you sure?  Your code iterates two nested arrays and it looks like it generates an array of these where each `kcs` property is itself an array: `{ "tag_id": "nienemk29290hu38", "kcs": [{ "kc_id": "nmdkwmswmwjm4944", "kc_title": "ABC"}, {"kc_id": "496jgwmwjm", "kc_title": "DEF"}]}`.  I can change mine to generate this.  Is that what you want?

Comment: yes. you got it right. This is exactly what I require.

Comment: This is the **Response** `[[null],[null]]`. I tried to print the `TagUnit` before return. No output at all. I guess somehow that part of the code is not getting executed.

Comment: @Rusty - Since I can't see the full code you have and I can't run/debug this at all, I can only make guesses.  I think you're going to have to put `console.log()` statements in various places until you get an idea what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Thanks. I got the required response with slight modification. Seems like `TagUnit` is immutable. So I created a dummy variable and used that to return instead of overwriting `TagUnit.kcs`. Something like this. 
`return {
        _id: TagUnit._id,
        kcs: results
};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118194/discussion-between-rusty-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises or [**Async**](https://github.com/caolan/async) module

```
var async = require('async');
...
function getKC (kc, callback) {
   KC.findById(kc, function(err, data) {
       if (err)
          return callback(err);

       callback(null, {kc_id: data._id, kc_title: data.title})
   });
}

function getKCs (tag, callback) {
   async.map(tag.kcs, getKC, callback);
}

async.map(Tags, getKCs, function(err, results){
    if (err)
       return console.log(err.message);

    res.json(results); // or modify and send
});
```

P.S. Perhaps, code contains errors. I cann't test it.